# Match regex with php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I get 2 results with `preg_match` and I don't understand why. This is my code:

```
$pattern = "\[precom\]([A-Za-z]|\(|\)|[0-9]|\s|\*)*\[\/precom\]";
$data = "[precom](homme) Cher monsieur $name[/precom] ";
preg_match("/" . $pattern . "/", $data, $m);
print_r($m);
```

This is the result:

```
Array ( [0] => [precom](homme) Cher monsieur *name[/precom] [1] => e )
```

Could anyone help me to find the problem please?

Comment: what does  $m in preg_match()?

Comment: Ah sorry, i edit, i do print_r($m)

Comment: There's no problem, that's the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.preg-match.php

#### matches

If matches is provided, then it is filled with the results of search. $matches[0] will contain the text that matched the full pattern, $matches[1] will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

Answer (score 4):

You should not parse HTML (or BBCode, etc) with regex. Try with:

```
$input = '[precom](homme) Cher monsieur $name[/precom]';
$dom   = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML(str_replace(array('[', ']'), array('<', '>'), $input));
$output = $dom->textContent;

var_dump($output);
```

Output:

```
string '(homme) Cher monsieur $name' (length=27)
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' on line 3

Comment: @Dexa that's because of older PHP version (which does not supports short array notation). I've edited my answer.